# How to boot as root without password on a headless Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: server, auto-login

I'm using a Pandaboard as a closed system (no Ethernet, wireless, or display) which runs ubuntu 11.04 server edition. I have a external power switch and I would like to boot up the system with this switch and launch a program automatically. That means I need to get around the login procedure. On top I need sudo rights to launch the program. 
Would be great to get your help.

Side question: At the moment I login in as a normal user and use `$sudo su` to get root rights. But when I want to login as root directly it says that my password is incorrect. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the root password yet? On default ubuntu installations, the root password usually isn't set. You could set it by `sudo passwd`. And then use that password for logging in as root. And as for the first part of your question, you could add the program to init scripts and it will run automatically on startup witout any login at all.